# Adjacent List - How to retrieve all sub nodes of a given parent by id?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like so

```
id          parent          title

1           NULL            Cars
2           1               Ford
3           2               Hatchback
4           2               Saloon
5           3               Fiesta
6           4               Mondeo
```

I need a query that will return a list of sub nodes for a specfic id.

For example, if I want all subnodes of id 2, I would get

```
3           2               Hatchback
4           2               Saloon
5           3               Fiesta
6           4               Mondeo
```

If I wanted all subnodes of id 3, I would get

```
5           3               Fiesta
```

A word of warning, the tree can be many levels deep, not just the few levels I have shown above of simplification. So I presume the query will need to be recursive in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use recursive query:

```
with T1 as
(  select t.* from t where parent=2
   union all
   select t.* from t 
     join T1 on (t.parent=T1.id)
)
select * from T1
```

[SqlFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cbdf6/3)

Answer (score 1):

You can create table valued function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [ftChildren]
(
    @id int
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
    WITH Tree(Parent, Title, ID)
    AS
    (
        SELECT Parent, Title, ID
        FROM TableName
        WHERE ID = @id
        UNION ALL
        SELECT s.Parent, s.Title, s.ID
        FROM TableName s JOIN Tree t ON t.ID = s.Parent
    )
    SELECT ID, Parent, Title
    FROM Tree
    WHERE ID != @id
GO
```

And use it as:

```
select * from ftChildren(2)
```